# Sign of permutation. Confusing example

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, permutations

Let $\sigma=(2314)\in S_4$. We have different definitions of sign of permutation.

1) Our $\sigma=(24)(21)(23)$ hence $\text{sgn}\sigma=(-1)^3=-1.$

2) Our $\sigma$ has two inversions namely $(2,1)$ and $(3,1)$. Hence $\text{sgn}\sigma=(-1)^2=1.$

This two differens answers confuses me.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permutation $\sigma$ as a map is

$$\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
4 & 3 & 1 & 2\\
\end{array}$$

The inversions are all pairs of indices $(i,j)$ where $i < j$ and $\sigma(i) > \sigma(j)$.

Then $(1,4), (1,3), (1,2), (2,3), (2,4)$ are all the inversions (only 6 pairs to check). This is odd as confirmed by the cycle formula.

You should not look at inversions in the order in the (disjoint) cycle representation, as you seem to do. The cycle is another way of representing the map (where each element is mapped to the next one in line, and the last to the first).

Comment: What was my mistake? I didn't understand

Comment: @A.Ward.2016 the way you counted inversions. $(2,1)$ cannot be an inversion by the standard definition. Like I said it's a pair $(i,j)$ with $i < j$..

Comment: Sure! Thank a lot!